# Is there a way to hide all option of removing a Google Chrome extension easily

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Say somebody has a productivity problem, and wants to install the [StayFocusd](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stayfocusd/laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji?hl=en) Chrome extension.

The extension does a decent enough job of making it difficult to change settings with the typing task option, however you can still easily just remove the extension via the 'manage extensions' page or by right clicking the icon and choosing 'Remove from Chrome'

You can sort of address the 'manage extensions' page by blocking the URL in StayFocusd, however there is no way to remove the icon from the top right, whether its on the drop down menu or the toolbar.

Is there some source code alteration or over-ride that can either hide this or disable the confirmation popup that appears when choosing 'Remove from Chrome'

Thanks

Comment: No, not really. This would be a huge security risk if it was possible.

Comment: The only method of abusing user's rights to remove an unwanted extension is to make a system utility that runs with system privileges.

Answer (score 3):

There is exactly one way to do it, [`ExtensionInstallForcelist` policy](https://cloud.google.com/docs/chrome-enterprise/policies/?policy=ExtensionInstallForcelist) for Enterprise Chrome deployments. This will prevent any local uninstall/disable.

However, this is only an option if you are in an enterprise environment (read: Active Directory domain) and can convince the domain administrators to set it up for you. In other words: unlikely.

Other than that there is no way, as Google actively, consistently and for quite some time is battling extensions that try to sneak in and be a pain to remove. Because, after all, the **main users of such tactics are malware writers**. The recent change to show a button in the toolbar you're talking about is just one of the many, many steps in this directions.

You need alternative solutions to what is essentially a human problem.

Comment: Google also provide policy settings for Mac and Linux users. Instructions are given here: https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-templates

Comment: FWIW, domain enrollment can be faked, see [Fake-MDM-Provider example](https://hitco.at/blog/apply-edge-policies-for-non-domain-joined-devices/) for Windows.

Answer (score 2):

As the other answers suggest, it may be difficult or impossible to do exactly what you want.

One alternative would be to use a **system-level self-control tool such as [Pluckeye](https://www.reddit.com/r/pluckeye/comments/7mdtz9/pluckeye_isnt_just_a_filter_it_can_also_help_you/)**.

If you don't want to use Pluckeye:

- You could use a **competing self-control tool**. For a list of some competing tools, please go [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/pluckeye/about/sidebar), then scroll down to "Other self-control software".
- Or: You could use a **parental-control tool**. And you could choose a difficult-to-remember parental password. Finally, you could store this password in [Lockbox](https://www.reddit.com/r/pornfree/comments/6amed2/lockbox_keep_your_passwords_out_of_your_reach/), so that you can't easily access it.

(Disclosure: I co-moderate the Pluckeye sub-Reddit.)

Answer (score 0):

from Q&A in StayFocusd

> Is there any way to remove the ability to disable/uninstall the
>   extension?
>
> Unfortunately, no. Chrome extensions can not remove the disable or
>   uninstall options. I do have a request in to the Chrome developers to
>   add this ability, but I don't expect them to implement my request
>   (ever).
>
> However, you CAN prevent yourself from accessing the extensions
>   settings page by adding chrome://extensions to your Blocked Sites
>   list. Once your time is up, you won't be able to access the settings
>   to disable StayFocusd.

Thus, we can only prevent ourselves to disable but not uninstall StayFocusd. I have to say this is the biggest bug of StayFocusd.

Answer (score 0):

Your question asks for a source code patch.

As Xiaoyu's answer suggests: Even if someone wrote such a patch, the Chrome developers would be unlikely to accept or carry it.

Chrome is a Blink-based Web browser. You could try asking maintainers of related Blink-based browsers to write and/or carry the patch.

You could visit:

- The [Vivaldi desktop feature-request forum](https://forum.vivaldi.net/category/185/desktop).
- The [Brave Browser issues page](https://github.com/brave/brave-browser/issues).

If they're unwilling to write the patch, you could ask if they might be willing to merge and carry a third-party patch. If so, you could write the patch yourself, or you could pay someone else to write it.

There are other, more minor, Blink-based browsers; they are listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Web_browsers). Either way, I encourage you to choose a browser which receives security updates at least once every two months; or preferably more frequently.

If you do submit a feature request to the Vivaldi and/or Brave teams, please leave a comment below with a link to the feature request. Perhaps we can then upvote it for you.

(Note: I haven't checked whether or not StayFocusd yet works at all on Vivaldi or Brave. I encourage you to check into this matter yourself, and to report back to us in the comments.)